# dpkg --list 'linux-image-*' results in Unknown / Not installed

Tags: package-management, kernel, dpkg

So I'm [manually deleting old kernels](https://askubuntu.com/a/153193/344926) and did a `dpkg --list 'linux-image-*'` and I get:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  linux-image-4. 4.10.0-42.46 amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.
ii  linux-image-4. 4.13.0-31.34 amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.
ii  linux-image-4. 4.15.0-38.41 amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-4. 4.15.0-39.42 amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-4. 4.15.0-42.45 amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-4. 4.4.0-128.15 amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.
ii  linux-image-4. 4.4.0-140.16 amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.
ii  linux-image-ex 4.4.0-128.15 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for ve
ii  linux-image-ex 4.4.0-140.16 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for ve
ii  linux-image-ge 4.4.0.140.14 amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
ii  linux-image-ge 4.15.0.42.63 amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
un  linux-image-un <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  linux-image-un <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  linux-image-un <none>       <none>       (no description available)
```

so the last 3 packages are in a `Desired=Unknown` and `Status=Not` state.

So I dug a little deeper and found that `dpkg-query --show 'linux-image-*'` doesn't help me much:

```
linux-image-4.10.0-42-generic   4.10.0-42.46~16.04.1
linux-image-4.13.0-31-generic   4.13.0-31.34~16.04.1
linux-image-4.15.0-38-generic   4.15.0-38.41~16.04.1
linux-image-4.15.0-39-generic   4.15.0-39.42~16.04.1
linux-image-4.15.0-42-generic   4.15.0-42.45~16.04.1
linux-image-4.4.0-128-generic   4.4.0-128.154
linux-image-4.4.0-140-generic   4.4.0-140.166
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-128-generic 4.4.0-128.154
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-140-generic 4.4.0-140.166
linux-image-generic             4.4.0.140.146
linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04   4.15.0.42.63
linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-38-generic
linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-39-generic
linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-42-generic
```

*So where are **those 3** coming from and how do I get rid of those 3??*

---

**Additional info:**

`dpkg --list 'linux-image-*' > /tmp/N0rbert.txt` is [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/TmcVJSR5RH/).

`uname -r` and `ls /boot` are [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/4kcXc9fBhq/)

Comment: Output of `dpkg -l` looks truncated. Please redirect its output to text file with `dpkg --list 'linux-image-*' > d.txt` and add contents of `d.txt` to the question.

Comment: Q edited as per your request.  **;-)**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before proceeding, compare the output of `uname -r` (your current running kernel version) with these versions. If you see the same number, then **those are not old kernels, but unsigned new kernels so don't delete them!**

---

Otherwise you can delete them using simply:

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-38-generic \
linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-39-generic linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-42-generic
```

These kernels came from the official repositories:

- [linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-38-generic](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=inux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-38-generic&searchon=names),
- [linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-39-generic](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=inux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-39-generic&searchon=names),
- [linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-42-generic](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=inux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-42-generic&searchon=names).

---

My personal methods of removing kernels is one of the following:

- use `apt-get autoremove`

  ```
  sudo apt-get autoremove
  ```
- use `purge-old-kernels` from `byobu` package:

  ```
  sudo purge-old-kernels
  ```
- remove non-installed kernels manually (if previous methods fail):

  ```
  sudo apt-get purge $(dpkg -l | grep 'linux-image-' | grep -v "^ii" | awk '{print $2}')
  ```

**Note:** `dpkg --list` may truncate its output when the terminal is narrow, so consider to use a redirect to file with `dpkg --list 'linux-image-*' > d.txt` and then `less d.txt`